# How do I cite without including a reference in the bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I would like to use the \cite command such that it includes in the text itself (Smith, 1990) or whatever is the right citation, but does not actually include a reference for it in the Bibliography section. Is that possible?

I am using natbib with the trucnat.bst bib style.

Comment: If you want no bibliography at all there exist various solutions. If you want to suppress only one entry it will be imho rather difficult with natbib. Then you should better switch to biblatex/biber.

Comment: yes, I just want to suppress a few entries. something like \citeButPutNoEntry{smith-90}

Comment: It can probably be done with a combination of a multibib package and a "nobibliography" code, but with biblatex it would be much easier. Can't you switch?

Comment: May I ask why you want something like this? You use \cite to declare where you got an information. For me it makes no sense that somebody wants to cite something but to not give the complete information.

Comment: Related: http://brianbuccola.com/how-to-cite-in-latex-without-the-citation-appearing-in-the-bibliography/